# Is there an encryption algorithm that doesn't use any bitwise operators?

Tags: encryption

I am currently trying to implement an encryption algorithm in a language that does not support any bitwise operations. Is there any algorithm currently out there that does this sort of thing?

Comment: There is really no programming language that doesn't have binary operators. Do you mean bitwise operators?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry.

Comment: [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) .. not that it's any way secure ..

Answer (score 0):

The only one I can think of off the top of my head is the relatively weak stream cipher [RC4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4), modified slightly to use bytewise addition to encipher and subtraction to decipher, instead of XOR (which is symmetric) to do both.